# Redshift insert bottleneck

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pentaho, amazon-redshift, kettle

I am trying to migrate a huge table from postgres into Redshift.

1. The size of the table is about 5,697,213,832
2. tool: pentaho Kettle    Table input(from postgres) -> Table output(Redshift)
3. Connecting with Redshift JDBC4

By observation I found the inserting into Redshift is the bottleneck. only about 500 rows/second.

Is there any ways to accelerate the insertion into Redshift in single machine mode ? like using JDBC parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main reason for bottleneck of redshift performance, which i considered is that Redshift treats each and every hit to the cluster as one single query. It executes each query on its cluster and then proceeds to the next stage. Now when i am sending across multiple rows (in this case 10), each row of data is treated a separate query. Redshift executes each query one by one and loading of the data is completed once all the queries are executed. It means if you are having 100 million rows, there would be 100 million queries running on your Redshift cluster. Well the performance goes to dump !!!

Using [S3 File Output](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/S3+File+Output) step in **PDI** will load your data to S3 Bucket and then apply the [COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-use-copy.html) command on the redshift cluster to read the same data from S3 to Redshift. This will solve your problem of performance.

You may also read the below blog links :

1. [Loading data to AWS S3 using PDI](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/loading-data-to-aws-s3-bucket-pentaho-data-integration/)
2. [Reading Data from S3 to Redshift](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/12/11/loading-data-from-s3-to-redshift-pentaho-data-integration/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: As an adendum to this if you could split your output into separate files on S3 then you can use the manifest facility to parallelize your loads.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-command-examples-manifest

Answer (score 15):

Have you consider using S3 as mid-layer?

Dump your data to csv files and apply gzip compression. Upload files to the S3 and then use `copy` command to load the data.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Comment: good idea, just want to know if there are other ways to load data into Redshift. like multi-thread insert into Redshift

Comment: I think it is the fastest way. In my case it took <4mins to transform and load 5M records = 20.000 rows per second (transformation on EC2 then transfer files to S3 and trigger copy command)

Comment: This is the most effective way of loading a table according to redshift docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_data.html

Comment: redshift is a columnar database technology, it is not designed for OLTP style single row inserts. I have used this product for more than 4 years, trust me whan I say batch loading with COPY is the fastest and correct way to load a lot of data. Gzipping is also good for the purpose of keeping your S3 costs down

Answer (score 0):

Better to export data to S3, then use COPY command to import data into Redshift. In this way, the import process is fast while you don't need to vacuum it.

Answer (score 0):

Export your data to S3 bucket and use the COPY command in Redshift . COPY command is the fastest way to insert data in Redshift .